# Get content type field value without entity

Tags: 7, entities, views, search

I have a exposed form and want to use my field "`field_region`" for the breadcrumbs. If a user now selects the exposed "`field_region`", my URL looks like "`?q=news&field_region=2`". Now I want to get the value behind the key "2" from the `field_region`.

Everything runs on a view-page, so I don't have any node / entity id to load the field value with. How can I get the value behind key "2" from the `field_region`? Or is there any other secure way of getting the selected value from the exposed filter?

Comment: Why do you want to get the exposed filter value? You want to use it anywhere? Can you please elaborate?

Comment: I want to use the filtered value to put it into my "fake" breadcrumbs. So e.g. "News / Filter Region Value" because it looks nicer if I can show the filtered region in the breadcrumb directly.